# ORA-01750: UPDATE/REFERENCES may only be REVOKEd from the whole table, not by column

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

why do i get ORA-01750: UPDATE/REFERENCES may only be REVOKEd from the whole table, not by column ?

```
SQL> revoke update(nama)
  2  on fauzi.mahasiswa
  3  from fauzi;
```

i get the error :

```
revoke update(nama)
             *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01750: UPDATE/REFERENCES may only be REVOKEd from the whole table, not by
column
```

Comment: If you look closely at the manual, you will see that the `revoke` command does not have that option: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_9013.htm#i2183500 vs. http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_9020.htm#i2123674

Answer (score 2):

You need to REVOKE from the entire table instead of a specific column. From [here](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_ora_01750.htm):

> **Cause:** Although it is possible to GRANT update privileges on a column-by-column basis, it is only possible to REVOKE them for an
>   entire table.
>
> **Action:** Do not identify specific columns. To revoke update privileges for certain columns, use REVOKE for the entire table and
>   GRANT the user privileges for specific columns.